# How do you uncheck HP Loadrunner VUGen to ALM connection on startup?

Tags: loadrunner, alm

VUGen 12.01 & ALM 11.52.

VUGen.
HP ALM Connection dialog 
“restore connection on startup” check box

Where is the “restore connection on startup” check box response recorded? and is it possible to change it outside of VUGen. 
I'm guessing it would be a reference to ALM-Client.exe in ALM app data or HP installs folders, ini or cfg file but I can't find anything

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to edit the flag from the config or ini file. You can check/uncheck the box from the LoadRunner UI.